# How to check if value is a reference from others sheet column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to auto-update a row in some sheet depending on antoher sheet. All this with a macro.

In the frist step I have:

```
SheetA!A$1 = "first"
SheetA!A$2 = "second"
SheetA!A$3 = "third"
SheetB!A$1 = empty
SheetB!A$2 = empty
SheetB!A$2 = empty
```

Then I edit SheetB!A$1 by hand

```
SheetA!A$1 = "first"
SheetA!A$2 = "second"
SheetA!A$3 = "third"
SheetB!A$1 = SheetA!A$1
SheetB!A$2 = empty
SheetB!A$2 = empty
```

Now the macro kicks in

```
SheetA!A$1 = "first"
SheetA!A$2 = "second"
SheetA!A$3 = "third"
SheetB!A$1 = SheetA!A$1
SheetB!A$2 = SheetA!A$2
SheetB!A$2 = SheetA!A$3
```

I would prefer to put the code into `SheetB`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1 'if changes in sheetB, col1
    'TODO
  End If
End Sub
```

How would such a auto-copy look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Sheets("SheetA").Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: SheetA shall be constant and never be altered. Further, the cells edited shall contain references not values.

Comment: @user1587451 if you want the cells to contain a formula, assign the cells' `Formula` property to a formula that refers to the address of the cell you want "linked". Your question is rather unclear TBH.

Comment: The code is in SheetsB, like you have asked for...Further why would you ask for VBA if you are just going to use formulas anyway?